# Can Google Identity Platform send claims tokens back to the server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mod-auth-openidc

I'd like to integrate Identity Platform with Apache's `mod_auth_openidc` to provide SSO on a site. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to do this, or even if it's possible.

I can get basic 'Sign in with Google' functionality by creating a Google app, with OAuth 2.0 Credentials, and this works by sending a JWT back to Apache on the server. However, this isn't good enough, since I need to add custom claims for the users to enable permissions-based access to different parts of the site. This means, I think, that I have to use Identity Platform and create and manage the users myself.

The problem is that Identity Platform doesn't seem to be JWT/OAuth-based, and instead expects you to use client-side JavaScript to authorise ([signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword)/etc). Is this right, or can I persuade Identity Platform to send a JWT back to Apache?

Comment: I think you want to generate OIDC Identity Tokens. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-configure-custom-claims#set_up_custom_claims I am not sure what Apache expects. Can you update your post with more details? I would remove some of your extra tags. That tends to get too many readers which results in your post being closed.

Comment: @JohnHanley: you're right, I need an Identity Token. With `mod_auth_openidc`, Apache acts as an OpenID Connect Relying Party, and expects an ID Token formatted as a JWT (which is what the basic Google App sends). Your link is good, but it implies that you would use `signInWithCredential` to authorise the end-user, but this is  a client-side JavaScript function so is of no use in an OpenID Connect setup.

Comment: AFAIK, Cloud Identity Platform can't act as an IDP, and your use case sounds needing that!